# Автоматическая связь с моделью базы данных в формах django

Tags: python, django

Есть цель добавить комментарии к фильму.

Модель фильма:

```
class Film(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Фильм"
        verbose_name_plural = "Фильмы"
        unique_together = ('name', 'year')
    AGE = ((0, "0+"), (1, "6+"), (2, "12+"), (3, "16+"), (4, "18+"))
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField('Описание')
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField("Год")
    age = models.IntegerField('Возрастное ограничение', choices=AGE, default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField("Картинка")
    image.short_description = "Image"
    genre = models.ManyToManyField("Genre", related_name="films")
    trailer = models.URLField('Трейлер', blank=True)
    time = models.PositiveIntegerField('Время')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        def slug_create(name, year):
            name = translit(name, reversed=True)
            return "".join((slugify(name), str(year)))
        self.slug = slug_create(self.name, self.year)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

и модель комментария:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    text_comment = models.TextField()
    data = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    vefiried = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    film = models.ForeignKey(to='Film', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

ну и сама форма

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ['user_name', 'text_comment']
    widgets = {
        'user_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-3', 'placeholder': 'Имя'}),
        'text_comment': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'col-12 my-2', 'rows': '10', 'placeholder': 'Комментарий'}),
    }
```

проблема в чем, я не знаю как автоматически связывать комментарий с фильмом, комментарий под которым был оставлен. Связи с юзером тут нет, просто связать с фильмом надо.

Comment: Добавьте вьюху добавления комментария, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил проблему переопределением метода save. Вот что я сделал:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    def slug_create(name, year):
        return "".join((slugify(name), str(year)))
    self.slug = slug_create(self.name, self.year)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

А может так?

```
class CommentInFilm(models.Model):
    film = models.ForeignKey('Film')
    comment = models.ForeignKey('Comment')
```